# Which files in a Visual Studio 2019 Release folder should be uploaded to GitHub?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, release

I recently created a simple program using Visual Studio Community 2019 and have shared it on GitHub. In order to help ensure that the program would work for others, I shared the entire release folder. However, while the .exe file is only 126 KB, the release folder itself is 11.8 MB, which makes me wonder which files I can exclude from GitHub in order to reduce the download size.

Here is what the release folder (sorted by size) looks like on my computer. Many of the largest components are .obj, .iobj, .pdb, and .ipdb files.

```
File:tz.obj
    2780 KB     8/18/2020   12:30:13 AM
File:CWClock.iobj
    2304 KB     8/18/2020   9:09:45 AM
File:CWClock.pdb
    1804 KB     8/18/2020   9:10:24 AM
File:CLClockv2.obj
    1769 KB     8/18/2020   9:10:23 AM
File:CWClock.obj
    1769 KB     8/17/2020   11:28:57 PM
File:vc142.pdb
    924 KB  8/18/2020   9:10:23 AM
File:CWClock.ipdb
    630 KB  8/18/2020   9:09:45 AM
File:CWClock.exe
    126 KB  8/18/2020   9:10:24 AM
File:CWClock.log
    1 KB    8/18/2020   9:10:24 AM
File:CWClock.exe.recipe
    1 KB    8/18/2020   9:10:24 AM
File:CWClock.vcxproj.FileListAbsolute.txt
    1 KB    8/17/2020   11:29:00 PM
CWClock.tlog
        8/18/2020   9:17:47 AM
```

I know that I'll need to share the .exe file, but what about the other items? If it would be helpful, you can find the GitHub page (which also includes the source code) [here](https://github.com/kburchfiel/ConsoleWorldClock).

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore?

Comment: Use the respective gitignore linked in the comment above.  In fact, there are actually plenty of libraries of good gitignore files, for practically every type of project imaginable.  You don't have to craft these files but can just use these and just comment out, or add specific files/directories as you see fit.

Comment: This is great, thanks! So do I just copy and paste that file into the same folder that contains my .git folder? Or do I have to enter it within the .git folder?

Comment: Put it in the root of your project. gitignore files can be specific to folders as well, so by putting it in your root, you're defining it for the entire application.

Comment: OK, so I think I included it in the root directory folder, but it appears that all the files in my release folder still uploaded to a test version of my project on GitHub . This was the first time I was uploading them as well. Perhaps I named the folder incorrectly? https://github.com/kburchfiel/SmallerCWC

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out--I needed to save it as just .gitignore with nothing before the period. Also, I found that I needed to include it within the Release folder; if I included it within the root folder, it wouldn't upload the Release folder at all (not sure why).